# Transaction timeout -Failed Terminating the transaction

Tags: timeout

I have recently installed the Ubuntu 22.04 in my Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5.
While booting I always get this message:

```
transaction timeout
failed terminating the transaction 
smbus is busy can't use it
```